# What is "as" meaning in this sentence?

Tags: meaning-in-context, parts-of-speech

> Owners often know what funds are needed day to day but are unclear
> **as** to how much revenue is being generated .. ([Reference](https://www.investopedia.com/articles/personal-finance/120815/4-most-common-reasons-small-business-fails.asp))

I can't understand why "as" used above.. can understand the overall meaning , though.
Can somebody teach me what "as"'s role in here?

Comment: _As to_ means the same as _about_ or _on the subject of_.

Comment: @KateBunting Thanks kate!! Can I use only "to how much.." without "as" ? Is it unnatural?

Comment: No - _as to_ has a definite meaning. You could say 'they are unclear _about_ how much revenue...'.